# How to draw contour of the heatmap and superimpose on original image using opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, overlay, heatmap

[image][image: heatmap]

I have measured the class activation maps and superimposed on the original image. Rather, I would like to include only the contour (in blue) of the heatmap and superimpose on the original image, so that the original image details are not obstructed. The code for creating the heatmap and superimposing on the original image is shown:

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)    
#Resizes the heatmap to be the same size as the original image
heatmap = cv2.resize(heatmap, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))    
#Converts the heatmap to RGB 
heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)    
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(heatmap, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
heatmap1 = cv2.cvtColor(heatmap, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(heatmap1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV 
|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
cnt1 = contours[1] #vary the contour number and see the performance
img1 = cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt1], -1, (255, 255, 255), 3)
```

Comment: Post your original image so others can use your images to test your code and make suggestions to answer your question.

Comment: @fmw42: Thanks, the original image is also posted, per your comments. The heatmap is generated through a lengthy process which i cannot post herewith. However, I believe the comments will hold good for any image other than the heatmap that can be superimposed on the original image.

Comment: Can you not post the heat map image? When you say "the contour in blue" do you mean the wide blue band or just its outer edge as the contour? Either way, just threshold the heat map image to binary for the colored region you show. Then get the external contour from findContours and draw that contour onto your input image.

Comment: @fmw42: It worked. edits made to the code, per your suggestions and added above.

Comment: @shiva: Just curious how did you overlay the heatmap on the grayscale image?